# Bit shifting repeating pattern

Tags: design-patterns, byte-shifting

I'm looking for a way to bit shifting this pattern:

6
24
96

All these numbers are multiples of 2 so I was thinking there would be a way to shift them

I want to shift them so I get the pattern but it keeps repeating possibly in a loop

6,24,96,6,24,96...

Programming language isn't important, the concept is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying a number by 2<sup>*n*</sup> is equivalent to shifting it left by *n* bits. Multiplying by 4 can be done by shifting left 2 bits.

> 06<sub>10</sub> = 00000110<sub>2</sub>
>   24<sub>10</sub> = 00011000<sub>2</sub>
>   96<sub>10</sub> = 01100000<sub>2</sub>

If you want to loop this pattern, you could *rotate* left rather than simply *shifting* left. To rotate left 2 bits you would shift left 2 bits and then bitwise OR the leftmost two bits back onto the right side of the number. If you were working with 8-bit numbers this would be written in C-like syntax as:

```
(n << 2) | (n >> 6)
```

Interestingly, if you rotate 96 left two bits you won't get 384 since that's bigger than an 8-bit byte can hold. Instead you get 129, because one of the 1 bits ends up rotating back to the right side.

> 006<sub>10</sub> = 00000110<sub>2</sub>
>   024<sub>10</sub> = 00011000<sub>2</sub>
>   096<sub>10</sub> = 01100000<sub>2</sub>
>   129<sub>10</sub> = 10000001<sub>2</sub>

If you then rotate 129 one more time you end up back at the beginning at 6.

Here's an interactive Python session demonstrating this. Note that `{0:3}` formats *n* as a decimal and `{0:08b}` as a zero-padded binary number.

```
>>> n = 6
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
 24 00011000
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
 96 01100000
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
129 10000001
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
  6 00000110
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
 24 00011000
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
 96 01100000
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
129 10000001
>>> n = ((n << 2) | (n >> 6)) & 0xFF; print '{0:3} {0:08b}'.format(n)
  6 00000110
```